# Why is answer 12541 deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

Why is answer [12541](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12541/3487) deleted?

- it shows no sign of plagiarism
- needs some editing to format the answer (new user after all)

Answer (score 1):

It was flagged for being low quality.  The moderator who handled that flag agreed.  Really not much more to it than that.

Comment: Don't know about others but I had an odd feeling for it too. Was waiting for others to share their thoughts. Plus I don't think we have fleshed out the rules for trivial questions.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Trivial questions are generally discouraged (see http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/56/22) since they rarely if ever attract the expert demographic a SE site needs, more rather it would drive them away.  Exactly where the line between "too trivial" and "easy, but interesting" lies is still rather up-in-the-air though.

Comment: your wiki link is for shia view only. but the question is not asking for shia view only.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala Then why is the question tagged [tag:shiism]?

Comment: @goldPseudo It wasn't tagged that by OP.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Then the question is still unclear, as I'm obviously not the only one who thought it was "asking for shia view only".  And this conversation has already strayed significantly from the actual point of why the *answer* is deleted.

Comment: Not straying from the point. Deleting the answer because the question itself wasn't unclear/trivial/easy, doesn't seem right/imbalanced treatment. Closing the question would be apt. The answer's content doesn't seem to have any issue. It's just the formatting (to me). New user after all. Plus it's not a good welcome for a new user.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Since I neither claimed that the answer was deleted because the question was trivial, nor am I even the one who actually *deleted* it, I'm still not sure how it's relevant at all.  I have removed the tangential action from my post to clarify the *actual* topic of this discussion.