# Is questionn 12524 really unclear?

Tags: discussion

Question [12524](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/what-are-the-titles-of-lady-fatimaha-s/12541#12541) is put on hold by claim of being unclear. putting on hold can be first steps of deleting a question that has received some useful answers in future.

It is clearly asking for titles of Lady Fatemeh a.s. (without specifying views of any sect).

But a moderator added the tag of shiism on it and them a moderator claimed it is trivial to find the answer in internet and then claimed to it be unclear and so can be closed or deleted.

I do not understand how it is unclear.

Please explain me what aspect of it is unclear? in my view it is completely a clear question.

It is asking for titles of daughter of prophet SAWW. but not from any specific view or any specific sect.

Also I am interested to know why a moderator added the tag of a sect to this question.

Such actions of moderators can be interpreted as sectarian actions and abusing moderation power.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a question is simple doesn't mean it's clear.  Under the general principle of [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), a clear question is one which can clearly be *answered*.

And this question doesn't really give any indication as to what would make an answer *acceptable*.

On the surface, it's just looking for "the titles of lady Fatimah".  From the [wikipedia link I provided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Shia_titles_for_Fatimah) in the comments, there's *well over a hundred* such titles.  If OP is seeking a comprehensive list, it's not only a textbook example of "too broad," but one that's well-covered by an *already existing resource*.

And that's just for Shi'a titles.  If, as suggested by the most recent edits, OP is seeking titles from [both Shi'a *and* Sunni sources](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1021/22), that number may well be more, and would again still be "too broad".

Given that the only resources in *the accepted answer* are clearly Shi'a and not Sunni, and that it only provides a dozen or so titles, the idea that OP actually *wants* both Shi'a and Sunni resources is questionable.  Or that OP even *wants* a comprehensive list.

But then that demands the question: What *is* OP looking for in an answer?  What makes this answer *useful* in any way shape or form?  What makes this answer *acceptable*?

Why do these dozen names get upvoted and accepted, when the dozen names posted by another user [gets flagged for deletion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023/22)?  I don't know. The question provides *absolutely no context* in which to judge a good answer from a bad one.

Maybe one of the users who actually upvoted the question could clarify it for the rest of us, as they obviously felt that it *showed research effort* and was *useful and clear*.  Or one of the users who actually upvoted the answer, since the only way they'd reasonably know the *answer* was *useful* is if they actually *understood what the question was asking for*.

These voters apparently understand the question better than I can, because as it stands it just looks like it's asking for a low-quality copy of an already-comprehensive Wikipedia page, which hardly seems of any value whatsoever to "[experts in Islam, students of knowledge, and those interested in Islam on an academic level.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"

If that's what OP's actually *asking* for, it's pretty much a textbook example of the sort of [boring trivial questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/285/22) that [drive away exactly the experts we need](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56/22) to make the site succeed.

Comment: why you assume seeking titles from sunni view will make number of titles more? perhaps in sunni she has no titles. she does not have unlimited titles. titles are given by prophet SAWW or God. a comprehensive list with reference can be a good answer. flags are for quality (ref, formatting,..). unclear and research effort are different issue. do not mix them here. if you show a wikipedia list covering both shia and sunni view then this is trivial. this question is about "unclear". so parts of your post about 'trivial" is irrelevant here.

Answer (score -3):

In my view this question is not asking for any specific view. and can be answered from different Islamic views. it is clear and finding the answer (from different views) is not trivial. so putting on hold or closing or deleting the question is wrong.